# How to format textutil -excludedelements

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, terminal, scripting, osx

I use `Geektool` on the Mac to display various information on my desktop. One feature of `Geektoool` is the ability to use shell mode to launch custom scripts or commands. I am not versed in any type of scripting, but find pieces on the web to use by copying and pasting. There are whole website dedicated to just this.

I have for a long time used a command to pull a one day weather forecast from Weather Underground. However they have changed their site and the output of the script needs to be edited. I am now getting duplicate information being displayed.

**Example**

```
Today is forecast to be Cooler than yesterday.
"weather_quickie": "Today is forecast to be Cooler than yesterday."
```

The script incorporates Textutil for the output.

```
curl -s http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=94965 | 
awk '/Today is/ || /Tomorrow is/' | textutil -convert txt -stdin -stdout -format html
```

From the man page of `textutil`, it seems like the option `-excludedelements` can be used to edit out the extra info. However I can't understand the `-excludedelements` explanation, nor figure out how to format it.

> excludedelements (tag1, tag2, ...) -  Specify which HTML elements
>   should not be used in generated HTML (the list should be a single
>   argument, and so will usually need to be quoted in a shell context).

I would like to edit out the "weather_quickie" part of the output. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Ramesh. It proved too difficult to install `w3m`. However, based upon your script, I just modified my original and I'm now getting the right output.

Before,

```
curl -s http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=94965 | awk '/Today is/ || /Tomorrow is/' | textutil -convert txt -stdin -stdout -format html
```

After,

```
curl ""http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=94965"" -s | textutil -convert txt -stdin -stdout -format html | awk '/Today is/'
```

Comment: Glad that it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `w3m` to do this.

```
curl ""http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=94965"" -s |  w3m -dump -T text/html > 1.txt | awk '/Today is/ || /Tomorrow is/' 1.txt
```

**Output**

*Today is forecast to be Much Cooler than yesterday. Afternoon thundershowers.*

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. I was aware I could use a text-based browser, but I'm out of my depth compiling and installing binaries. But I'll search around how to install w3m.

Comment: If you are using debian based systems, you can find it installed by default. It is pretty useful, hope you find it in your machine :)

Comment: Running Mac OSX 10.7.5. But I'm following a lead to install w3m. I'm sure I will figure it out!